SMB Mount despite being connected to local network (MacOS 13.7.1)
I'm flabbergasted by an unexpected SMB mount on my MacOS. Here the situation

I'm not connected to my local network (actually in a hotel connected through a vpn to the internet, hence not even the IP range is anywhere similar)
I noticed my nas being available in the finder. The SMB ports are not forwarded by the router at home. The router has a DSLit IPv6 address, i.e. no (static) IPv4
I can actually access the files on the nas, so this is not a ghost from the past or pure metadata cache.

I have no idea how that works! Unfortunately MacOS is terrible in getting information out. Here a few things I've tried, especially to try to pin down how my Mac is connecting to the (very) remote nas
dscacheutil -cachedump -entries nas.local
Unable to get details from the cache node

dns-sd -B _smb._tcp
Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type         Instance Name
17:19:55.433  Add        2  17 local.               _smb._tcp.           NAS

dns-sd -L NAS _smb._tcp
Lookup NAS._smb._tcp.local
DATE: ---Wed 20 Nov 2024---
17:21:39.439  ...STARTING...
17:21:39.628  NAS._smb._tcp.local. can be reached at nas.local.:445 (interface 17)

The local IP address of the nas can't be pinged. Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
If anyone has an idea how the mechanics work, I'd be very interested in understanding this!
Cheers,
U

Synology?  Don't they run a forwarding service that you can use to allow access to their products from outside?  What is the result of a traceroute to the NAS?

Nope. Self-made NAS running Debian. I'm pretty sure it's macOS remembering an IPv6 address. I just can't get the OS to spit it out

If it is through public IPv6, you can get it from your NAS. On your Mac, try netstat -na |grep tcp | grep -e 445 -e 139.

What was the result of the traceroute?

@JohnSiu that shows only the IPv4 of the VPN connection

@MarcWilson that shows a 192.168.191.0/24 address that links to a feth interface, which does not show a public IPv6 in ifconfig

Check routing table, it show both IPv4 and IPv6:
netstat -rn
Check multicast IP of the nas device:
dns-sd -G v4v6 nas.local

There it is. Brilliant! Thanks!

Good one! However, according to man dns-sd your answer may have a short life span...: Because its command-line arguments and output format are subject to change, invoking it from a shell script will generally be fragile.  :)

@Mulle So is it really because of IPv6?

@Seamus That is more of a concern if it is used inside shell script. Additionally, dns-sd is a BSD command, which did not change for years since IPv6 support was added.

Fair enough... did not notice its BSD heritage as it's not mentioned in the man page.

@Seamus Most MacOS command line utilities are BSD base, except Apple/MacOS specific ones like defaults, launchctl, etc.

Maybe, but I'm used to seeing some notation to that effect at the bottom of the man page; e.g. in man mount, near the bottom in the HISTORY section... A mount command appeared in Version 6 AT&T UNIX., or BSD 4.  I was "under the impression" such a notice was required - even under the uber-liberable BSD license.

@Seamus I made a mistake. Though dns-sd is available in BSD (no linux package), it is originated from Apple. The mDNS standard was submitted by Apple. mDNS is protocol/standard, dns-sd is command line tool for it.
